# How can I refactor this code snippet to make it more efficient?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a matrix of actions based off game theory. So if two people meet, they can either both share, or one steal, or both steal, etc.

The outline of what I have looks like this (not the whole matrix, just so you get an idea):

```
if first_agent.type == "AlwaysShare" and second_agent.type == "AlwaysShare":
    pass
elif first_agent.type == "AlwaysSteal" and second_agent.type == "AlwaysShare":
    pass
elif first_agent.type == "AlwaysShare" and second_agent.type == "AlwaysSteal":
    pass
```

Clearly this is very inefficient and prone to mistakes. How can I optimise this so I can efficiently manage interactions for the matrix?

Comment: How many different types of interactions are there? Is it just share vs steal? If so, you could store the different possibilities in tuples as keys in a dictionary: `(share, share), (share, steal), (steal, steal), (steal, share)` which you'd then check against the tuple `(first_agent.type, second_agent.type)`.

Comment: For now there are just 2, but I'm planning on adding more so it should be flexible enough to support this

Comment: Well that's perfectly flexible. You'd generate a cartesian product of the possible actions with itself for as many times as there are agents: `itertools.product(possible_actions, repeat=num_agents)`

Comment: This question is pretty vague though, and I think likely to be opinion-based. You'd be better off writing more code and then posting on the code review stack exchange.

Comment: @ddejohn Yeah using product should be a best practice to generate the combinations.

Comment: FWIW if it doesn't matter which agent does something, you only care about when one does something and another does something else, then you can generate combinations instead of the cartesian product, and then lookup the tuple and the reversed tuple to get the proper course of action.

Comment: It might be good to pull those repeated type strings into variables, or make an `enum` for them to avoid typos in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have a situation with multiple options, I like to make a dictionary of functions that handle the different possibilities. The keys are the encoded and normalized inputs. In your case, you can generate a key like this:

```
def key(first_agent, second_agent):
    key = [first_agent.type, second_agent.type]
    key.sort()
    return tuple(key)
```

Then your dictionary would look something like this:

```
def handle_share():
    pass

def handle_one_steal():
    pass

def handle_both_steal():
    pass

# Etc.

action_map = {
    ('AlwaysShare', 'AlwaysShare'): handle_share,
    ('AlwaysShare', 'AlwaysSteal'): handle_one_steal,
    ('AlwaysSteal', 'AlwaysSteal'): handle_both_steal,
}
```

If you scope the functions carefully (e.g., make them methods or nested functions as necessary), you can fine-tune any side effects you may need them to have.

Now you can replace your `if`-block with something like:

```
action_map[key(first_agent, second_agent)]()
```

Use `action_map.get` instead if you have a suitable default or no-op in mind, and don't want to get `KeyError` for potentially unknown interactions.

The nice thing about doing it this way is that you can easily add new interactions: just implement a function and register it in the dictionary. Want to have a third agent? Make `key` accept `*args` instead of a fixed number of agents. Need to define another type of agent? No problem. And so on.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied but I think this lays it out the most clearly and understandably. Thanks a lot, I'll implement what you've suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You can build a lookup matrix.

```
def action1():
    print("Doing action 1")

def action2():
    print("Doing action 2")

def action3():
    print("Doing action 3")

def action4():
    print("Doing action 4")


lookup = {
    "AlwaysShare": {
        "AlwaysShare": action1,
        "AlwaysSteal": action2,
    },
    "AlwaysSteal": {
        "AlwaysShare": action3,
        "AlwaysSteal": action4,
    },
}

action = lookup[first_agent.type][second_agent.type]
action()
```

Comment: This looks good, sort of the thing I was after. Where you've written "action", would those be functions?

Comment: My answer is similar to yours, but we envision the keys a little differently. +1

Comment: @Cypher236 Yes, `actionX` is suppose to be a function that you can call.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, it might make sense to check for matches vs. mismatches first:

```
if first_agent.type == second_agent.type:
    action = first_agent.type
    if action == "AlwaysShare":
        do_something()
    elif action == "AlwaysSteal":
        do_something_else()

else:
    whatever_happens_if_mismatch()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the game, and my approach is similar to @Mad Physicist. The key here is to have a look-up table (matrix). The trick is to always put sharer first in order for look up to succeed:

```py
def share_share(agent1, agent2):
    print(f"Both share: {agent1} and {agent2}")
    
def steal_steal(agent1, agent2):
    print(f"Both steal: {agent1} and {agent2}")

    
def share_steal(sharer, stealer):
    print(f"{sharer=} and {stealer=}")
    

def interact(agent1, agent2):
    matrix = {
        ("AlwaysShare", "AlwaysShare"): share_share,
        ("AlwaysShare", "AlwaysSteal"): share_steal,
        ("AlwaysSteal", "AlwaysSteal"): steal_steal,
    }
    if agent2.type == "AlwaysShare":
        agent1, agent2 = agent2, agent1
    func = matrix[agent1.type, agent2.type]
    func(agent1, agent2)
```